# deleting a bundle removes fields

Tags: entities

my module main_module adds an entity my_entity and a field the_field that has

```
'entity_types' => array('my_entity')
```

main_module also has this:

```
function main_module_field_attach_create_bundle($entity_type, $bundle)
{
    if ($entity_type == "my_entity"){
        field_create_instance(
            array(
                'field_name' => 'the_field',
                'entity_type' => 'my_entity',
                'bundle' => $bundle,
                'label' => 'Users',
                'required' => TRUE,
                'widget' => array(
                    'type' => 'options_select',
                ),
            )
        );
...
}
```

another_module (dependent on main_module) adds a bundle of my_entity, and therefore automatically gets the field instance.

the problem is that when i uninstall another_module, I call
entity_delete('my_entity', $key_of_bundle) ;

which removes the instances (OK) but also the fields themselves which mean I need to reinstall main_module in order to get them back.

thanks